# Not able to change dialog box background?

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I know this is very bad. From couple of hour I am trying to change the `theme` for `AlertDialog` but not to do so.

**parent theme :**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary_background</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_background</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_background</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/primary_background</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/myDialog</item>
</style>
```

**Dialog theme :**

```
<style name="myDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="dialogPreferredPadding">@dimen/dialog_padding</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.myDialog));
```

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong. I think this is very easy .

Answer (score 1):

I. Declare custom drawable background_dialog.xml for dialog background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<!-- From: support/v7/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_dialog_material_background_light.xml -->  
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:insetLeft="16dp"
    android:insetTop="16dp"
    android:insetRight="16dp"
    android:insetBottom="16dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/indigo" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

II. Declare custom styles in your styles.xml file.

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">  
    <!--buttons color-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/pink</item>
    <!--title and message color-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--dialog background-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_dialog</item>
</style>
```

III. Create your dialog and use style as parameter in AlertDialog.Builder.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder =  
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
...
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();  
// display dialog
dialog.show();
```

Checkout this [document](http://www.materialdoc.com/alerts/) for more details.

**OR**

You can set custom view of dialog programmatically like below way.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```

then after, you can get reference of component as below

```
 Button btn = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
```

Comment: this only change the bottom line where ok and cancel written.

Comment: Try with setting `colorBackground` property in style like this `<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>`
`

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal Check my edited answer and try using that code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it `xml` Style you can acheive it simply programatically below way.

Create your xml file that you have to show in the `AlertDialog`.

**Example :** name is `abc_dialog.xml`.

Now do this way

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_dialog, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
```

and set that view to your `AlertDialog`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```

Comment: What if I need to change the background color, text color.?

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal change the background color as I suggest you can easily change the background color in file you created `abc_dialog.xml` as i suggested in the answer.

Comment: That way I have to change background color for each dialog box.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal Yes that is the simple way.

Comment: Thats not the simple way

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your DialogFragment class.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if(dialog!=null)
    {
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_contract);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(1000, 1500);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background_my_background);
    }
}
```